# TypeScript, function as an object property

Tags: typescript

I would like to store functions in object and access to them by a key without call.
I have object named `methods` with functions stored with a `string` key. It works if function is assigned manually `methods["myMethod"]` but if I try to assign it with `string` variable I get error:

> `element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ myMethod: () => void; }'.`. How should I understand it?

```js
const args = parse(Deno.args);

// Should I define type somehow? 
// Maybe something like object<string;Function> in C-like languages?
const methods = {
    "myMethod": (): void =>{
        console.log("WOOOW");
    }
}

if (args.m) {
    const methodName: string = args.m;

    // works
    const method: Function = methods["myMethod"];

    // Error: element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ myMethod: () => void; }'.
    const methodFromArgs: Function = methods[methodName];

    // go
    method();
}
```

Comment: Can it help? `const methodName: keyof typeof methods = args.m;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've defined `methods` with type `{ [key: string]: Function }` instead of default `any` and it works fine.
  As long as I am new to TypeScript I am not sure if it is best practice.

```js
const methods: { [key: string]: Function } = {
    "myMethod": (): void => {
        console.log("WOOOW");
    }
}

if (args.m) {
    const methodFromArgs: Function = methods[args.m];
    methodFromArgs();
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is, that you can pass anything in place of `args.m`, which will result in getting `undefined` for everything that is not the string `myMethod`.

Comment: @MikeS yea I know. What is the best practice for this? Something like `if (typeof a_string === 'string') return false;` ?

Comment: `args.m` should be of type `keyof typeof methods`, whereever its coming from. Another way is to simply check `if(methodFromArgs) methodFromArgs()`

Answer (score 0):

this may help u.

```
`
 const getVal = <U extends keyof T, T extends object>(key: U) => (obj: T) =>
 obj[key];
 const user: details = {
    name: "abc",
    age: 25
 };   

 const getUserDetails = getVal<keyof details, details>("name")(user);

 //abc -name
`
```